# Error subscription in cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I am having problems when creating a subscription in cygnus.
I really think the error is from the contextBroker since it appears in the log - this is the information that it shows:

```
Time = 2017-08-07T10: 48: 09.360Z | Lvl = WARN | Corr = N / A | Trans = 1502101560-775-00000000006 | From = pending | Srv = pending | Subsrv = pending | Comp = Orion | Op = AlarmManager.cpp [328]: notificationError | Msg = Raising alarm NotificationError http: // localhost: 5050 / notify: (
Easy_perform failed: Could not connect to server)
```

I have open ports.
My subscription status is failed.

How can I solve that?

EDIT

The creation is as follows:

```
{
  "description": "A subscription to get info about Room1",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "Room1",
        "type": "Room"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "pressure"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://localhost:5050/notify"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "temperature"
    ],
    "attrsFormat": "legacy"
  }
}
```

When I perform the subscription on fiwarelab in the orion machine already created if it works, but when I try on a machine centos 6 and performing the installation steps is when I get that error.

I have already solved the problem and it was setup.

The steps I followed with the following:

To install cygnus:

1st install java and maven as it puts on the web of fiware
2nd install with yum install cygnus
3º Install apache flume as it puts on the web of fiware
4th install mySQL
5th configure the agents

Everything works already.

Comment: Could you edit your question in order to explain how are you doing the step of "creating a subscription in Cygnus"? I mean, the exact request your are doing for that. Thx!

Comment: Buenas, @fgalan


acabo de editar el post

Comment: Just a guess: try change `http://localhost:5050/notify` to `http://CYGNUS_IP:5050/notify` . Note that the `localhost` will only work in this case if cygnus is installed in the Orion host/VM/container.

Comment: Hello,

ContextBroker and Cygnus are installed on the same machine.

Comment: Good,

I have already solved the problem and it was setup.

The steps I followed with the following:

To install cygnus:


1st install java and maven as it puts on the web of fiware
2nd install with yum install cygnus
3º Install apache flume as it puts on the web of fiware
4th install mySQL
5th configure the agents

Everything works already.

Comment: Good to know you finally solved it! :) It would be great if you self-answer your question in order to describe the solution that you found.

Comment: I'd suggest to move the answer part (i.e. from "I have already solved the problem and it was setup") to a proper Answer at SOF.

Answer (score 1):

I have already solved the problem and it was setup. The steps I followed with the following:

To install cygnus:

1. install java and maven as it puts on the web of fiware
2. install with yum install cygnus
3. Install apache flume as it puts on the web of fiware
4. install mySQL
5. configure the agents Everything works already.

It should be noted that this is for the cygnus version of 0.13. I'm trying to make it work in version 1.7 in the next post

[ContextBroker subscriptions Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545475/contextbroker-subscriptions-error)